# Wubi shows error

Tags: installation, dual-boot, windows, wubi, iso

I tried installing Ubuntu 12.04 using Wubi and it just doesn't work, every time, without fail. I had the following scenarios:

```
1. I downloaded only wubi.exe and ran it.  
The wubi installer started downloading the amd64.iso using torrent. But when there were just about 40 secs left to download, it shows an error 404: File not found.    

2. I downloaded the iso file seperately and put it in the same folder as the wubi.exe. Now there are two cases:  

  a. Offline: wubi says it could not download the metalinks file and hence cannot download the iso.
So I download the meta files separately and place them in the same directory. wubi shows the same error again. 

  b. Online: wubi works in same way as in case 1. and the same problem occurs as in case 1.  
In short wubi doesn't recognize the already downloaded iso in the directory at all.  

3. I burn the iso into a Cd and run it. The same thing occurs as in Case 2.
```

Just in case that you know, I installed SP3 for win XP just before using wubi. While Windows is running alright, is it possible that its causing conflicts for wubi?

Comment: First do you have xp 64bit? if so, have you downloaded 64bit ISO? If no then ubuntu tries to download 64bit ISO. To use 32bit ISO, you need to run wubi with `--32bit` parameter. [More details](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/WubiGuide#Can_I_force_Wubi_to_download_and_install_a_32_bit_version_of_Ubuntu.3F)

Comment: No my xp is 32 bit. But I think that my cpu can run 64 bit.(because  I ran the 64 bit version of anaconda- The fedora installer- and it ran just fine) Also wubi automatically tries to download the amd64 version. So I thought that this must be the correct iso.

Comment: No default download from ubuntu site is 32bit. Did you explicitly changed the download option? try with 32bit argument as in the instruction of that page.

Comment: @Web-E No the ubuntu page doesn't allow explicit installers for wubi acc. to system architectures. However if my system is capable of 64 bit then I want to install 64 bit ubuntu. However I think, I'll try your suggestion. BTW do u think that I should try the "avoid md5 sum check" option. Maybe then it will not download the meta files?

Comment: No I was talking about the ISO you downloaded.. it must be 64 bit .. by default ubuntu provide 32 bit ISO. IF 32bit ISO, you need to run wubi.exe with `--32bit` argument

Comment: Yes the iso I downloaded is amd64 i.e. 64bit. I downloaded it only because wubi seemed to download the same.

Comment: Please edit your question with a link to the log file. You can find it in the `%TEMP%` directory called `wubi-nn.nn-revnnn.log`. [Pastebin](http://paste.ubuntu.com/) the contents. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I also have 12.04 alongside Ubuntu in my Windows XP, and I've also encountered same errors while trying to use Wubi

I guess that wubi failed in locating the .iso installation file. In my case, I paste the Ubuntu iso in the Windows root directory (C:), open the iso without extracting using winrar, and double click the wubi.exe inside, and everything goes well.

Comment: I tried doing the same thing as above except I put the `ISO` in another drive except the root Windows drive. But the same error occurred. But I tried this with a program similar to Wubi for Linux Mint called `Mint4Win` and it ran fine. Dunno what's the problem. Using Mint for now.

Comment: Try to put the ISO in the root Windows drive, just checking if it works